# how can i inject the keycloak seesion in the web api by using spring security adapter?

Tags: spring-security, keycloak

I need help on how to bring the keyclaok session in the web application.

I'm using the spring security adapter and authentication is successful.

However, after logging in the application, instead of keycloak session I'm getting the application session.

Comment: any help appreciable

Comment: i did very sample poc here i'm able to logout success fully using the sso/logout, comes to my web application i'm unable to logout by using web app

Comment: ` instead of keycloak session i'm getting the application session` show us your code